# Is there in Mathematica something like class in Java or struct in C?

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

I am new to Mathematica and I am very impressed with its features. Although I don't understand how to do a simple thing: for example, I want to create few point variables (say a,b,c,d,e), each storing its x and y coordinates. In Java, I would write something like this:

```
class Point {
    float x;
    float y;

}
...
Point a;
a.x = 2,5;
a.y = 1,2;
```

How do I do same thing in Mathematica? Thank you!

Comment: Just define `n`-dimensional points/vectors as length `n` lists; e.g. `a = {2.5, 1.2}`.

Comment: @J.M. How do I access elements?

Comment: Mathematica is not object-oriented. I suggest you [go through a few tutorials](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/12) and see how things are usually done the Mathematica way.  What you know from Java or C should not be your starting point when learning Mathematica.

Comment: Look up `Part[]` and `Extract[]` in the documentation. Try e.g. `a[[1]]`
.

Comment: "How do I access elements?" By reading the documentation. A minimal level of Mathematica knowledge is expected before you ask questions here.  I am not being snarky. JM's answer is technically accurate, but you would not usually work this way with a 2D vector most of the time.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE! Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) as it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e it arises from simply not reading the documentation, at all, and is unlikely to help any future visitors. Don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your future [good questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are welcome. Learn about [common pitfalls here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/10397). To learn more about Mma.SE, please **take the [tour] now**.